# DDS not saving entity when specifying id

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

When specifying a given id to an entity before persisting it using a dynamic data store in episerver, the entity is not persisted. According to tutorials I have seen this should have been just fine. Any clues? No exceptions are thrown, and the Save call returns the Id of the entity I specified the id of.

```
var winnerEntity = new DailyXMasLotteryWinner
{
    Id = Identity.NewIdentity(guid),
    FullName = fullName,
    Email = email,
    Phone = phone,
    WinnerTime = DateTime.Now
}

winnerStore.Save(winnerEntity); // does not persist to database!
winnerStore.Items().Count() == 0;
winnerEntity.Id = null;
winnerStore.Save(winnerEntity); // persists to database just fine!
winnerStore.Items().Count() == 1;
```

Comment: Could it be that the "Id" property name is protected, so its value should only be set if overwriting an existing object? In other words, if your property was called "WinnerId" instead, it would work?

Comment: What does your `guid` parameter contain, how do you construct it?

Comment: It's a Guid. Created by Guid.NewGuid()

Comment: I'll check it out, Ted, as I was just mimicking your 2009 tutorial on the subject :-) I'll report back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of your patterns but this is how I typically implement DDS

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using EPiServer.Data;
using EPiServer.Data.Dynamic;
using EPiServer.ServiceLocation;

namespace Herlitz.EPiBlog.Models.DDS
{

    public interface IDailyXMasLotteryWinner
    {
        DailyXMasLotteryWinner Create(string fullName);

        DailyXMasLotteryWinner Get(string fullName);

        bool Exist(string property, string value);
    }

    [ServiceConfiguration(typeof(IDailyXMasLotteryWinner))]
    public class DailyXMasLotteryWinner : IDailyXMasLotteryWinner //,IDynamicData
    {
        private readonly DynamicDataStore _store = DynamicDataStoreFactory.Instance.CreateStore(typeof(DailyXMasLotteryWinner));

        public Identity Id { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public DailyXMasLotteryWinner Create(string fullName)
        {
            if (Exist(property: "FullName", value: fullName))
            {
                return Get(fullName: fullName);
            }

            Id = Identity.NewIdentity(Guid.NewGuid());
            FullName = fullName;

            _store.Save(this);
            return this;
        }

        public DailyXMasLotteryWinner Get(string fullName)
        {
            return _store.Find<DailyXMasLotteryWinner>(propertyName: "FullName", value: fullName).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public bool Exist(string property, string value)
        {
            return _store.Find<DailyXMasLotteryWinner>(propertyName: property, value: value).Any();
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with this

```
@{

    var xmasLocator = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDailyXMasLotteryWinner>();
    var winner = xmasLocator.Create(fullName: "Ned Flanders");

    <div>@winner.Id @winner.FullName</div>
}
```

And it works

[image]

Obviously you should adapt this to your patterns, if it doesn't work it would probably be your database user that has insufficient rights.